# Как вывести double с заданным количеством символов перед запятой?

Tags: c++, c, вывод, форматирование

Мне нужно значение `double` перевести в строку с определенным количеством символов до и после запятой. Я использую функцию `snprintf()`:

```
char buffer[400];
int n = snprintf(buffer, 400, "%.0f", 1234.5678);
```

В строке формата можно указать количество символов после запятой, и функция выведет либо округленный вариант, либо дополнит вывод нулями.

Могу ли я с помощью этой функции регулировать вывод количество знаков до запятой? Например:

```
 01234.5678 // 5 знаков до запятой, 4 знака после запятой 
 -1234.5678 // 5 знаков до запятой, 4 знака после запятой 
-01234.5678 // 6 знаков до запятой, 4 знака после запятой
```

Если с помощью `snprintf` нельзя получить такой результат, то, может быть, есть другие функции в `stl` или стандартной библиотеке языка C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double d = 1234.5678;
snprintf(...,"%010.4lf\n",d);
snprintf(...,"%010.4lf\n",-d);
snprintf(...,"%011.4lf\n",-d);


cout << setprecision(4) << setfill('0') << fixed << internal;
cout << setw(10) << d << endl;
cout << setw(10) << -d << endl;
cout << setw(11) << -d << endl;
```